# Encontrar una palabra en un string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista, bucles

Resulta que estoy haciendo un code que busque una palabra fija dentro de strings que entran por un input.

Ejemplo yo quiero ver si la palabra "mascota" tiene una subsecuencia, osea que se obtiene manteniendo el orden de los caracteres originales.

> input(ftlmhastcopetra) ----------> tiene el "m a s c o t a"
>   manteniendo el orden
>
> output("SI")
>
> input(nmakdscomsha)    ----------> no tiene el "m a s c o t a"
>
> output("NO")

Answer (score 2):

Solución de expresión regular

```
import re


def check(s, x): 
    r = '.*'.join(x)  # Inserta '.*' entre todas las letras de la palabra buscada
    return re.search(r, s) is not None

print(check("ftlmhastcopetra", "mascot"))  # True
print(check("nmakdscomsha", "mascot"))  # False
```

Solución con un simple bucle for

```
def check(s, x):
    i = 0
    for c in x:
        i = s.find(c, i)
        if i == -1:
            return False
        i += 1

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

espero que te valga. Puede usar el comando "find" como te pongo en el código. Un saludo

```html
cadena = "ftlmhastcopetra"
if cadena.find("mascota") >= 0:
    print ("Se ha encontrado la mascota en el e-mail")
else:
        print ("No se ha encontrado la mascota en el e-mail")
```

Comment: El `find` solo encontrara la cadena buscada si estan todos los caracteres seguidos, no es lo que se esta preguntando.

Comment: No te entiendo, lo que persigue es obtener la palabra que sea manteniendo el orden de los caracteres  originales, tal y como muestro en mi ejemplo. Un saludo

Comment: Al ejecutar tu ejemplo el `find` retorna -1 por que no encuentra la cadena "mascota" ya que en la cadena original no esta, segun el enunciado tendria que devolver `true` al estar los caracteres en el orden necesario (ftl**m**h**as**t**co**pe**t**r**a**) para formar la cadena de busqueda

Comment: LLevas razón, disculpa. Gracias